# why am i getting the same dates in the x axis?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <head>
    <title>Simple Line Graph using SVG and d3.js</title>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="json.js"></script>
    <style>
      /* tell the SVG path to be a thin blue line without any area fill */
      svg {
        border: 1px solid red;
      }

      .text-anchor{
      font-size: 15px;
      }

      path {
        stroke: steelblue;
        stroke-width: 1;
        fill: none;
      }

      .axis {
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
      }

      .x.axis line {
        stroke: lightgrey;
      }

      .x.axis .minor {
        stroke-opacity: .5;
      }

      .x.axis path {
        display: none;
      }

      .y.axis line, .y.axis path {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #000;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>


  <div id="graph" class="aGraph" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0; float:left;"></div>


  <script>
    /* implementation heavily influenced by http://bl.ocks.org/1166403 */

   var json = ["{\"created_at\":1385481755,\"rankings\":[[\"#OBAMA\",91],[\"#TCOT\",65],[\"#OBAMACARE\",26],[\"#IRAN\",25],[\"#MTVSTARS\",20],[\"#BENGHAZI\",17],[\"#TEAPARTY\",16],[\"#LNYHBT\",12],[\"#PJNET\",11],[\"#CARAMEL\",11]]}","{\"created_at\":1385481749,\"rankings\":[[\"#OBAMA\",90],[\"#TCOT\",64],[\"#OBAMACARE\",26],[\"#IRAN\",25],[\"#MTVSTARS\",19],[\"#BENGHAZI\",17],[\"#TEAPARTY\",16],[\"#LNYHBT\",12],[\"#PJNET\",11],[\"#CARAMEL\",11]]}","{\"created_at\":1385481743,\"rankings\":[[\"#OBAMA\",90],[\"#TCOT\",64],[\"#OBAMACARE\",26],[\"#IRAN\",25],[\"#MTVSTARS\",18],[\"#BENGHAZI\",17],[\"#TEAPARTY\",16],[\"#LNYHBT\",12],[\"#PJNET\",11],[\"#CARAMEL\",11]]}","{\"created_at\":1385481737,\"rankings\":[[\"#OBAMA\",93],[\"#TCOT\",63],[\"#OBAMACARE\",28],[\"#IRAN\",27],[\"#MTVSTARS\",18],[\"#BENGHAZI\",17],[\"#TEAPARTY\",16],[\"#PJNET\",12],[\"#POPCORN\",11],[\"#CARAMEL\",11]]}","{\"created_at\":1385481731,\"rankings\":[[\"#OBAMA\",91],[\"#TCOT\",64],[\"#OBAMACARE\",29],[\"#IRAN\",27],[\"#MTVSTARS\",17],[\"#BENGHAZI\",17],[\"#TEAPARTY\",15],[\"#POPCORN\",11],[\"#CARAMEL\",11],[\"#IMMIGRATION\",11]]}","{\"created_at\":1385481725,\"rankings\":[[\"#OBAMA\",61],[\"#TCOT\",63],[\"#OBAMACARE\",28],[\"#IRAN\",26],[\"#MTVSTARS\",17],[\"#BENGHAZI\",16],[\"#TEAPARTY\",13],[\"#IMMIGRATION\",11],[\"#CARAMEL\",11],[\"#POPCORN\",11]]}","{\"created_at\":1385481719,\"rankings\":[[\"#OBAMA\",93],[\"#TCOT\",64],[\"#OBAMACARE\",28],[\"#IRAN\",26],[\"#MTVSTARS\",18],[\"#BENGHAZI\",16],[\"#TEAPARTY\",13],[\"#IMMIGRATION\",12],[\"#CARAMEL\",11],[\"#POPCORN\",11]]}","{\"created_at\":1385481713,\"rankings\":[[\"#OBAMA\",93],[\"#TCOT\",33],[\"#OBAMACARE\",28],[\"#IRAN\",26],[\"#MTVSTARS\",18],[\"#BENGHAZI\",16],[\"#TEAPARTY\",13],[\"#IMMIGRATION\",12],[\"#POPCORN\",11],[\"#CARAMEL\",11]]}","{\"created_at\":1385481707,\"rankings\":[[\"#OBAMA\",94],[\"#TCOT\",66],[\"#IRAN\",28],[\"#OBAMACARE\",28],[\"#MTVSTARS\",18],[\"#BENGHAZI\",16],[\"#TEAPARTY\",13],[\"#IMMIGRATION\",12],[\"#CARAMEL\",11],[\"#PJNET\",11]]}","{\"created_at\":1385481701,\"rankings\":[[\"#OBAMA\",94],[\"#TCOT\",66],[\"#IRAN\",28],[\"#OBAMACARE\",28],[\"#MTVSTARS\",16],[\"#BENGHAZI\",16],[\"#TEAPARTY\",13],[\"#PJNET\",12]]}"];
    //parse json
    $.each(json,function(index,value){
      json[index]= JSON.parse(value);
    });

      var startTime = new Date(1385481173);
    var endTime = new Date(1385481173+6000);
    var timeStep = 300000;

    // define dimensions of graph
    var m = [80, 80, 80, 80]; // margins
    var w = 1000 - m[1] - m[3]; // width
    var h = 400 - m[0] - m[2]; // height



    //specify ranges and domains    
    var x = d3.time.scale().domain([d3.min(json,function (d){return d.created_at}),
                                    d3.max(json,function (d){return d.created_at})]).range([0, w]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, d3.max(json, function (d) {
            return Math.max(d.rankings[0][1],d.rankings[1][1]);
      })]).range([h, 0]);



    var line = d3.svg.line()
      // assign the X function to plot our line as we wish
      .x(function(d,i) { 
        //console.log(d);
        //console.log('Plotting X value for data point to be at: ' + d.created_at + ' using our xScale.');
        return x(d.created_at); 
      })
      .y(function(d) { 
        //console.log('Plotting Y value for data point to be at:' + d.rankings[0][1] + " using our yScale.");
        return y(d.rankings[0][1]); 
      })

      // Add an SVG element with the desired dimensions and margin.
      var graph = d3.select("#graph").append("svg:svg")
            .attr("width", w + m[1] + m[3])
            .attr("height", h + m[0] + m[2])
          .append("svg:g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + m[3] + "," + m[0] + ")");

      // create yAxis
      var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).tickSize(-h).tickFormat(d3.time.format("%H:%M:%S"));

      // Add the x-axis.
      graph.append("svg:g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + h + ")")
            .call(xAxis)
            .selectAll("text")  
          .attr("class","text-anchor")
          .attr("dx", "-2.48em")
          .attr("dy", ".15em")
          .attr("transform", function(d) {
           return "rotate(-65)" 
      });

      // create left yAxis
      var yAxisLeft = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).ticks(9).orient("left");
      // Add the y-axis to the left
      graph.append("svg:g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
           // .attr("transform", "translate(-25,0)")
            .call(yAxisLeft);

        // Add the line by appending an svg:path element with the data line we created above
      // do this AFTER the axes above so that the line is above the tick-lines
      graph.append("svg:path").attr("d", line(json));


  </script>



  </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to display only hours:minutes:seconds in the X-axis but it seems like d3 is not converting it right, what am it doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that dates in Javascript are in milliseconds since Epoch, not seconds. The dates in your JSON are in seconds, so you need to multiply by 1000:

```
var x = d3.time.scale().domain([d3.min(json,function (d){return d.created_at * 1000}),
                                d3.max(json,function (d){return d.created_at * 1000})]).range([0, w]);
// ...
line.x(function(d,i) {
    return x(d.created_at * 1000); 
  })
```

Complete jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WTVEL/1/).

On a general note, you could use [`d3.extent()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-d3_extent) instead of `min` and `max` separately:

```
var x = d3.time.scale().domain(d3.extent(json,function (d){return d.created_at * 1000}))
                       .range([0, w]);
```

Comment: is there a way to have multiple lines on the same graph? it can't find a good example